# connect asp repeaters with objects outside repeaters

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a dropdown in my repeater.. i want to copy its value to textbox that is outside repeaters..

here is what I want to do

copy value from `dropdown[1] to textbox1`
copy value from `dropdown[2] to textbox2` and so on...

here is my code

ASP:
    `<asp:DropDownList ID="fmFrom" runat="server"  Height="20px" Width="120px" DataSourceID="BrDatasource" DataTextField="branchName" DataValueField="branchCode" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="fmFrom_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>`

c#:

```
protected void fmFrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rateRepeater.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DropDownList from = (DropDownList)rateRepeater.Items[i].FindControl("fmFrom");
        TextBox1.Text = from.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

here all my textbox gets the value of the last dropdown only...
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
protected void fmFrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rateRepeater.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DropDownList from = (DropDownList)rateRepeater.Items[i].FindControl("fmFrom");
        ((TextBox)FindControl("TextBox" + (i + 1))).Text = from.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
TextBox1.Text = from.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

to:

```
TextBox1.Text += from.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: when i do this.. this gives me the value of all the dropdowns in one single dropdown.....